# How do I extend someone else's repo manifest?

Tags: yocto, repo, openembedded

In my project, I want to take an existing Yocto setup for the Automotive Grade Linux distribution and add some layers with recipes for our own components.

There exists a manifest file, publicly available, on  [their gerrit site](https://gerrit.automotivelinux.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=AGL/AGL-repo.git;a=blob;f=default.xml;h=40b2f8384ca7b13cdad7c008eb74f17e52f64f1d;hb=refs/heads/master). What I'd like to do is basically

```
<manifest>
    <include url="<url of AGL manifest>" />
    <remote name="mysite" fetch="ssh://gerrit.mysite.com" />
    <project name="mylayer1" path="mylayer1" />
    <project name="mylayer2" path="mylayer2" />
</manifest>
```

The aim being that a `repo init` command pointed to my manifest first fetches all the repositories mentioned in the "included" manifest, then proceeds to fetch all my own meta layers.

The problem is that the `include` element is meant for including other manifests within the same repository specified on the `repo init` command line.

I *could* simply copy their manifest into my own repository, with a different name, and create my own manifest along side it. Or I could just reproduce their file and edit it.

But maintaining it will be a pain and extremely error prone. Especially as the upstream manifest is used not only to specify the repositories, but to pin each one to specific commits as a form of version control within Yocto.

I can't believe such an obvious use-case hasn't been considered and addressed.

So, at the risk of being closed as "too broad" or for requesting recommendations, has anyone already solved this problem? If so, how?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? It still appears there is no clean way to do this. local_manifests doesn't really appear to do what I want, maybe I need to continue looking into that.

Comment: @user_ABCD Nope - never did

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt there is a way to do this using the repo tool.

Wind River has a solution, and there has been talk of moving this into oecore:

https://github.com/Wind-River/wr-lx-setup

I'm not sure if this will do exactly what you are looking for, but it solves the problem that you are describing.

Historically, people have used repo (freescale-community-bsp), combo-layers (Ostro), or simply rolled their own solution. This setup tool is an attempt to standardize the way layers are assembled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use local_manifest.xml. Under **.repo/** create a directory named **local_manifests/**. You can add a file **local_manifest.xml**

You can add you own remote, default and projects that are to be fetched from that remote.

I have used this feature with repo 1.23